# Extract original audio stream from file that had music added to it

Tags: audio, video, editing

I downloaded a file and it has music added over top. I was wondering if there is a way for me to remove the music stream so that I can restore the original audio stream from when the video was made?

Also you should know I'm not good at code.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If there was an original video with an audio track and later someone added music to it by mixing it over the original audio, it's impossible to “un-mix” those two signals again. Your file has only one audio track, so there's nothing to separate.

PS: The only exception is signals where the stereo layout would allow you to extract certain components. A typical example is a “karaoke effect”, where you'd pull out vocals from pop music, since those are typically mixed dead-center and lie within a known frequency range, and therefore are easier to separate from other instruments. There are tools for this that are [sold commercially](https://audionamix.com/), but there are [some other free tools](https://www.lifewire.com/best-free-programs-to-remove-vocals-from-songs-2438491) as well. And the sound-engineer's perspective on this is [described here](http://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/extract-vocals-stereo-mix).